# AfterEffect. Arrow with stationary origin, moving head

Tags: after-effects, animation

need help animating an arched arrow in adobe after effect. Here is an animation “draft” of what type of movement i need to create:

[image]

That is: The origin of the arrow stays static, but the arrow head moves along a path. And the arrow is not straight but curved just like in the linked video.

P.s. any linke to the youtube videos or articles would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an easy path arrow preset like this one:
https://kylasaurusrex.gumroad.com/l/LNSVU

It’s “pay what you want”.

Comment: Is there a way to see what is inside this package? I mean, the links to the video there lead to some other youtube tutorials